# What is Cumulative Impact Index of a journal?

Tags: publications, journals, bibliometrics, impact-factor

I recently came across the term "Cumulative Impact Index". I came to know about it [here](http://bietjhs.ac.in/pdf/faculty_qualification.pdf), which includes the statement, "publication of
5 International Journal papers, **each Journal having a cumulative impact index** of not less than 2.0".

I knew of peer-reviewed, but as this term was bit new I surfed the web and visited [Impact Factor on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor), but it is still not clear.  Can any one of the learned members may kindly explain to me, preferably with an example?

Comment: Related: [The Agony and the Ecstasy—
The History and Meaning of the Journal Impact Factor](http://www.garfield.library.upenn.edu/papers/jifchicago2005.pdf?wa=IPEMBI14) Doesn't go into the math specifically from a quick scan, but basically, impact factor is a correlation between number of times a journal's article is cited to how many articles it publishes.

Answer (score 5):

The term "Cumulative Impact Factor" (or cumulative impact index) has been used with different meanings by different authors.

One definition is that the cumulative impact factor for an individual author is simply the sum over all papers that the author has published of the impact factors of the journals that the papers were published in.  e.g.

You've published 3 papers in Journal A that has impact factor 1.2.
You've published 1 paper in journal B that has impact factor 1.9.
You've published 2 papers in journal C that has impact factor 1.7.

Your CIF would then be

CIF=3*1.2+1*1.9+2*1.7=8.9

Like all bibliometrics, it's a very crude measure.   You can get a high score on this measure by publishing a lot of research in journals that aren't very prestigious, or by publishing a very small amount in highly prestigious journals.

Furthermore, the metric says nothing about the impact of your research compared with other papers in the journals in which you've published (e.g. you might have published a very widely cited paper in a journal with a low impact factor but you won't get any extra credit for that.)

The term "cumulative impact factor" has also been used for measures of the impact factor of a journal over extended periods beyond the usual definition of impact factor.  See for example:

http://www.garfield.library.upenn.edu/papers/impactofcumimpfacs.pdf

I don't believe that ISI has ever defined this term in their formal reports on the impact factors of journals, so I'm afraid that any use of the term will depend on the particular group or person that is computing the cumulative impact factor.

Comment: From the quoted statement, the OP is clearly asking about the latter, so maybe you can elaborate on that.

Comment: I don't think that there is any one standard definition of the cumulative index factor/index for a journal.  You could extend the usual two year period to five years, or ten years, or to the life of the journal, or ...

Comment: There are apparently a bunch of universities in India that want faculty to have published at least "five papers in journals with a cumulative impact index of 2.0."  Presumably these universities are using a report that someone used the raw ISI data to get these cumulative impact indices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and discussion. But one or two things are slightly confusing till. I am getting back to you soon. Regards, Subhabrata.

Comment: So, here["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Linguistics_%28journal%29"] does Impact Factor come for 2009? Regards, Subhabrata.

Comment: Subhabrata; your link is broken, but I assume that you intended to link to the Wikipedia article on the impact factor.  The regular impact factor includes only citations of articles published in the last two years.  Cumulative impact factors extend this period to some longer time period.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you. I am reposting the link. It is the Wikipedia article on Computational Linguistics(MIT Press Journal). ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Linguistics_%28journal%29"] Regards, Subhabrata.